# JupyterLab does not work when redirected using TLS

Tags: nginx, ssl, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I have a local jupyter lab instance, running on `mint-2` computer with command `jupyter lab --ip "*"`, and it listens to port 8888. I can access it just fine via the URL `mint-2:8888`.

I also have a server instance `ubuntu-2`. I reverse ssh tunnel from `mint-2:8888` to `ubuntu-2:8888`, meaning I can access it on my `mint-1` laptop just fine via the URL `ubuntu-2:8888` anywhere in the world.

However, it is not encrypted with TLS, so I wanted to improve this. On `ubuntu-2` I have an nginx load balancer container that strips https traffic, and redirects http traffic to other locations. I have set up `jupyter.ubuntu-2:443` so that it redirects to `ubuntu-2:8888` so that it redirects to `mint-2:8888`. This version initially seems to open up just fine, and I can navigate directories. However, whenever I want to launch a new terminal or notebook instance, or even create new directories, it wouldn't work. Here's the network log when I save a modified notebook:

[image: netlog]

My question is, why won't the requests go through, considering I can still interact with the interface just fine everywhere else, but just not when creating folders/notebooks/terminals. I am thinking that JupyterLab might be using UDP and I'm considering passing UDP traffic through nginx, but this doesn't really make sense, as this is clearly a PUT request. Any other help regarding where to find more logs or speculation on what might have gone wrong is much appreciated.

Comment: This problems seems like it has occurred before https://github.com/chaoleili/jupyterlab_tensorboard/issues/22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dig into it a little more, and managed to figured it out.

JupyterLab has CORS policy that doesn't allow requests to `ubuntu-2`. I then added `c.NotebookApp.allow_origin = "*"` to JupyterLab's config at `~/.jupyter/jupyter_lab_config.py`, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/issues/79).

Then I found out that everything is still not functional, and this is because Jupyter requires both HTTP and WebSocket protocols, and my current server setup only allows http traffic. So I need to enable generic TCP traffic on `ubuntu-2`'s HAProxy load balancer. Because I have multiple virtual hosts on the server, I need to distinguish between them, so I used [Server Name Indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), server name included in TLS traffic.